# Regexp in JavaScript to find text between two sentences in multi-line string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have the following text to match for a regex:

```
[dshow @ 000000000359bd00] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 000000000359bd00]  "Logitech HD Webcam C270"
[dshow @ 000000000359bd00]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_046d&pid_0825&mi_00#7&316d5db0&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\{bbefb6c7-2fc4-4139-bb8b-a58bba724083}"
[dshow @ 000000000359bd00] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 000000000359bd00]  "Microphone (HD Webcam C270)"
[dshow @ 000000000359bd00]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{2B89B488-1611-4574-B524-38A86F459087}"
[dshow @ 000000000359bd00]  "Microphone (Jabra UC VOICE 150a)"
[dshow @ 000000000359bd00]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{9EEC135F-7CA8-453F-8DB1-A8C8244EB2F1}"
dummy: Immediate exit requested
```

I've written a regex and it works in RegExr [here](http://regexr.com/3bmca).

But when I run it in my node.js application like this:

```
        var expr = new RegExp('DirectShow video devices \(some may be both video and audio devices\)[\s\S]*(.*)DirectShow audio devices', 'm');

        var responses = expr.exec(ffmpegOutput);
```

`responses` is null. What am I doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: escape all the backslashes one more time.

Comment: Just use a literal notation `/.../m`.